# JQuery Common HTML Header/Footer Redirect Issue?

Tags: jquery, html, header, footer

I have successfully created a common HTML template for both the Header and Footer on my website using the following code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
$(function(){
$("#header").load("header.html"); 
$("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
</script>
```

However when I check my site on tools.pingdom and in Google Page Insights it tells me the following:

> Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
>   https://www.website.co/header.html
>   https://www.website.co/header

Is there anyway to remove the redirect issue given I know the exact name of the file for the header is header.html?

Answer (score 0):

1. First double check if you are site is http:// or https:// and check accordingly.
2. You can fix it by turning off data collection for Remarketing and Advertising Reporting Features under the Tracking Info -> Data Collection section in Analytics admin

source:
https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/forums/v3_1/forumtopicpage/board-id/Code_Implementation/thread-id/3876/page/3

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This did solve the issue with the Google Analytics redirect. But i still have the issue with header.html and footer.html redirecting. Any other ideas?